# Calling delegate result in error "unasigned"

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to write on screen result i get after completing actions at the bottom of the code. But i don't want to use Console.WriteLine() in "IF" function i want to call it as delegate carying value but it says unasigned. (site says mostly code but i dont have to say anything else so i just type something here :D )

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class program
    {
        delegate int first(int a, int b);  
        static void Main()
        {
            first beta;
            int result;
            Console.Write("insert number A: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int a);
            if (a == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not a number");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            Console.Write("insert number B: ");
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a == 0)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("not a number");
               Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("plus(1) or minus (0)");  
            int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (c == 1)
            {
                beta = plus;
                result = beta(a, b);  
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (c == 0)
            {
               beta = minus; 
               result = beta(a, b); 
               Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            beta(); // PROBLEM HERE, I WANT TO WRITE ANSWER FROM THIS 
                    //instead of "Console.WriteLine(result);" inside function

       }

        private static int plus(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        private static int minus(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

Example what i mean i want to accomplish but a bit in different way.

```
using System;
namespace consoleApplication4
{
  class Program{

Delegate void Message();

     static void Main (string[] args)
{

Message mes;

if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
{
mes=GoodMorning;
}

else{
mes=GoodEvening;
}

mes();  //this does what i want here but in code above something is missing
Console.ReadKey();
}


private static void GoodMorning(){
console.WriteLine("Good Morning");
}
Private static void GoodEvening(){
Console.WriteLine("Good Evening");
}}}
```

Comment: Do you want to write to console without calling `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: where i marked problem area. That word "beta" is carrying value after there was completed (private static ...) And i want to get that answer using "beta" outside if functions

Comment: your `beta` containing a delegate, not a result. Also, your `beta` expects 2 parameters to be passed in, so just calling `beta();` will not work anyway.

Comment: i think we need to learn to walk before we can run

Comment: delegate is pointed at one answer (either a+b or a-b) i just want to get that answer outside of if functions

Comment: again, delegates are holding a reference to a **method, not a results** of a previous method calls. So in your second example `mes = GoodMorning;` means that when anybody calls `mes();` he actually calling `GoodMorning();` and a `GoodMorning` method in turns calls `Console.WriteLine("Good Morning");`

Comment: @JohnB has posted [a link that might be useful for you](https://code-maze.com/csharp-delegates/) in another question (accidentally, I suppose), so I will retranslate it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have correct code to call your delegate in both branches of `if`. So to get code almost working those two lines calling `beta` need to be moved out of both branches:

```
    if (c == 1)
    {
       beta = plus;
    }
    else if (c == 0)
    {
       beta = minus; 
    }
    result = beta(a, b); 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Now the other problem is still there - your `if` checks have 3 outcomes (0, 1, other) but `beta` is only assigned in two of cases. So we need to add that "other" case too with some desired output (or simply failure), `switch` statement expresses it better than chained ifs:

```
    switch (c)
    {
      case 1: beta = plus; break;
      case 0: beta = plus; break;
      default: beta = (a,b)=>""; break;
      // alternatively to fail: default: return 0;
    }
    result = beta(a, b); 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```